# Android fragments and memory

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-management

I am starting a new app which will include the usage of a lot of fragments.

I started building it, but there is something that bother me...

I made a very simple sample to illustrate what I want to do :
https://github.com/Kobatsu/fragmentstests

There is a button in the action bar to change the main fragment. Each fragment contains only a TextView with a sample text.

It's working, but everytime I click on the button to change the fragment displayed, the memory used by my app (I'm seeing it in AndroidStudio) increase.

It doesn't increase a lot since there is nearly nothing in each fragment, but in my real app it increase more and if I swap a lot between the fragments, I can get an OutOfMemoryException.

Is there something I need to do to remove the fragments from memory ?

Answer (score 0):

I've read your code in github, it seems fine in memory aspect.
If your fragment's `onDestory()` or `onDestroyView()` is invoked successfully, usually you don't need to worry about memory.

It's true that `Fragment` creation will cost memory, but when your memory usage increase to a certain limit, `garbage collection` or `GC` will check unused heap objects and free them.

Be careful when other objects potentially hold the fragment instance: like register listener to other thread, or `addToBackStack` that keeps fragment in stack.

Comment: Even after garbage collection, it doesn't go back to the memory the application used at first so if I keep swapping between the two fragments, at some point I'll have an OOM I guess. Why doesn't it come back to the initial amount of memory it used?